# Call TabBarController delegate from View Controller - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I have an iOS application built on the Parse backend. I have set a `UITabBarController` in `AppDelegate` and this works correctly.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var tabBarController: UITabBarController?
var array: [AnyObject] = []

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.setApplicationId("1040205491TFSDJT43T49T349F3I4T3J")
    var navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearance.tintColor = uicolorFromHex(0xffffff)
    navigationBarAppearance.barTintColor = uicolorFromHex(0x4183D7)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = titleDict
    //navigationBarAppearance.clipsToBounds = true;
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
    let myVC2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navProfile") as UIViewController
    let myVC1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigation") as UIViewController
    let myVC3 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navComp") as UIViewController
    var controllers = [myVC1,myVC3]
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    var query = PFUser.query()
    return true
}
```

However my application uses a login and when the user logins in I wish to display the tab Bar controller. This is my login view controller

```
@IBAction func SignIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    LoginViewController().showActivityIndicator(self.view)
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(UsernameTextField.text,password: PasswordTextField.text){
        (user:PFUser!, error:NSError!)->Void in
        if user != nil{
            println("Login successfull")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigation") as UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil);
```

However this links to the `UINavigationController` with identifier "navigation"
Is there a way to sent a storyboard identifier for the tab bar controller created in `Appdelegate` or somehow instantiate to the view

Comment: If you're using a storyboard, why are you creating the tab bar controller and its children in the appDelegate? Create them all in the storyboard.

Comment: I need the controllers to be selected according to user status. For example if the logged in user is a Student then myVC1 and myVC2 are displayed, if its Employer then myVC1 and 3 are displayed. This code is not present above in order to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting to work on a similar project. I don't know if it is the best practice, but I will have the AppDelegate check if there is a logged in user and then select which view should be presented.

The main reason for this approach, is because if you can't present a View on whose view is not in the window hierarchy. This way you won't have the view present itself and then present another view, making the process smoother.

Hope this serves

```
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    if user == nil {
        // Do stuff after successful login.
        println("Login Not Succesful")
    } else {
        // The login failed. Check error to see why.
        println("Login Succesful")
        var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabbc") as! UITabBarController

        window?.rootViewController = viewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```